# Calculate values of flags for Intel 8086

Tags: c#, flags, x86-16

I'm implementing a simulator for Intel 8086 and want to know how to calculate each of: carry flag, overflow flag, auxiliary carry flag.

I know what does each one represents (carry flag to indicate if there an overflow from bit 7, etc). But, how to implement this using C#.

For example, in case of carry flag and ADD instruction, I simply check the value after addition, if it exceeds 0xFF then the flag is raised. But this gives incorrect values in some cases.

I have read some where that I should check bit 7, if it set before addition and cleared after addition, then there is a carry. but this gives wrong values with other instructions like SUB?

Can anybody explain clearly a general rule to implement the 3 flags (carry, AC, OV)?

Comment: Did you find an answer? If not, try reading this http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt

Comment: Before attempting to solve this problem, you should first educate yourself, when you should use comma or period in sentences, why we start each sentence with a capital letter etc. This will generally help you understand, why people are downvoting your questions (at least thoses people, who doesn't like garbage in questions and lazy writers).

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the lower 8 bits of the flag register to ah using the LAHF instruction (the LAHF instruction doesn't requires arguments)
The bits of AH now will be:

```
(7) 128: Signflag
(6) 64: Equal/Zero-Flag
(5) 32: reserved for future purposes
(4) 16: Auxiliary-Flag
(3) 8: reserved for future purposes
(2) 4: parity-Flag
(1) 2: reserved for future purposes
(0) 1: Carry-Flag
```

If you want to copy the hole flag register to ax use this code:

```
pushf
pop ax
```

The bits of AX now will be:

```
15: reserved for future purposes
14: Nested-Task
13: I/O Privileged Level
12: I/O Privileged Level
11: Overflow-Flag
10: Direction-Flag (see also: STD, CLD)
9: Interrupt enable (see also: STI, CLI)
8: Trap-Flag (Trap mode)
7: Signflag
6: Equal/Zero-Flag
5: reserved for future purposes
4: Auxiliary-Flag
3: reserved for future purposes
2: parity-Flag
1: reserved for future purposes
0: Carry-Flag
```

To check a single byte, use the TEST instruction (if your assembler supports the TEST instruction) or use this code:

```
shr ax, (bitposition) ;replace "bitposition" by the position of the flag (for example 2 for the parity flag)
and ax, 1; If the flag wasn't set, ax will be zero otherwise, if the flag was set, ax will be 1.
```

Or if you used LAHF:

```
shr al, (bitposition)
and al, 1; If the flag wasn't set, al will be zero otherwise, if the flag was set, al will be 1.
```

Comment: This does not seem to be an answer to what the OP is asking. The way I am reading it, he's asking for a definition for when a flag is set, not how to get at the flag values.